# Android Google Location services - class implementation

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm trying to get used to implementing the Google Play Location Services into an existing app.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a tutorial that can walk me through this?

I've got a class/app that can pin my location onto a map but I want to use the lat/long numbers in another app. I have no idea how to link the class that I have to the app I've created.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

OSH.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio it is easy using https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those once I've got my head round the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read all the information you can find from this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html

When you are done with it, start with:

1) Set up google play services from the link above

2) Run samples: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api

3) read more documentation about Google Maps API v2 from the first link guidelines

Comment: Thank you for the info - appreciated. I'll read through the links and work from there.